# Compile Mathematica code

Tags: compile

Considering  mathematica code

```
range = Range[4 10^6];
Position[Mod[10^5 NestList[Mod[ 10^6 #, 1355297] &, 10^6,Length[#] - 1] - (54 # + 46), 1355297], 0] &[range]
(* {{2331259}, {3776127}} *)
```

which works as expected  I intend (performance issue)to compile the code.
All the functions involved are compilable as

```
Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort
```

shows but the approach

```
fu = Compile[{{range, _Integer, 1}},Position[Mod[10^5 NestList[Mod[ 10^6    range, 1355297] &, 10^6,Length[range] - 1] - (54 range + 46), 1355297], 0]]
(*Compile::cset: Variable Compile`Variable$630 of type 
{_Integer,0}    encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}. *)
```

doesn't work. 
Checking the compiled code

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[fu]
```

I recognize, that NestList doesn't appear!!

My questions:
Is NestList compilable ? Is there a workaround to make the compile-code run?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you want this?:

```
fu = Compile[{{range, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Position[Mod[
    10^5 NestList[
       Mod[10^6 #, 1355297] &,  (* N.B. range -> # *)
       10^6, 
       Length[range] - 1] - (54 range + 46), 1355297], 0]]
```

Comment: Yes , thank you! Silly mistake...